# Chrome extension browser action only works once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When a user clicks the browser icon, spiderSimulator() should run.
I can get it to work – once.

Like, I’ll click the icon and it does what it’s supposed to. But if I refresh the page and click it a second time, it doesn’t work. if I go to another site and try again, it doesn’t work.

If I update the extension, refresh the page, and clear the cache, it works again – sometimes. it’s super inconsistent.

Any idea what’s going wrong here?

content.js

```
// Adds an event listener to the browser icon to sends a message to background.js.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "clicked_browser_action") {
            console.log( 'send message' );
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "spider_simulator"});
        }
    }
);
```

background.js

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // Send a message to the active tab
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        console.log('browser action');
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "spider_simulator") {
            console.log('run the spider');
            spiderSimulator()
        }
    }
);

// removes the site's stylesheet and replaces it with my own; 
// turns all page elements into nested list items. 
function spiderSimulator() {

    console.log( 'inject stylesheet' );
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS({
        file: 'search-spider-simulator.css'
    });

    console.log( 'execute script' );
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'search-spider-simulator.js'
    });

    window.close();
}
```

Comment: window.close() in the background page makes no sense, it most probably terminates it. Also you don't need chrome.tabs.query since onClicked gives you tab object in its parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by wOxxOm, `window.close()` executed in the *background page* acts on itself - essentially terminating the background portion of your extension.

Not sure what was meant there; if you need to close the tab you're talking to, then this also needs to be `executeScript`'ed.